# different result update and select using join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I tried to **update** some record using the following sql syntax

```
update product_class1 t1 
join product_class1 t2
on t1.family_code = t2.family_code
set t1.parent_id = t2.id
where t1.id < 145
and t1.id > 140
and t2.class_code = ''
```

it gives me zero (0) record result

while i tried to do **select** statement using the similar sql syntax

```
select *
from  product_class2 t1 
join  product_class2 t2
on  t1.family_code = t2.family_code
where t1.id < 145
and t1.id > 140
and t2.class_code = ''
```

it gives me 4 records result.

I don't know what's wrong with my **update sql statement.**
Appreciate if anyone can point out the suggestion.

regards

Comment: I'm not sure  if this is the case but please notice that in your update query you join `product_class1` with itself and in the select query `product_class2` also with itself. Could you verify and eventually update the question? (in short you try to update basing on `product_class1` and select only from `product_class2`)

Comment: for update you are doing self join on product_class1 and in select you are doing self join on product_class2. in Both the queries you are referring different tables.

Comment: yes, sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the `update` query - you're joining `product_class1` with itself instead of using `product_class2`. Just fix the `join` statement, and you should be OK.

```
update product_class2 t1 --here!
join product_class2 t2 -- and here!
on t1.family_code = t2.family_code
set t1.parent_id = t2.id
where t1.id < 145
and t1.id > 140
and t2.class_code = ''
```

Comment: actually the update statement should using product_class2, same with select statement and it works.

Comment: @Frans arg. updated - I misread the select. How embarrassing :-(